# Cant get past the ubuntu splash screen after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: boot-failure

i had being using ubuntu 11.10 in my HP core2duo vista laptop since the past six months. yesterday i upgraded to 12.04 and during upgrade got an error message of "partial upgrade.''Today morning I booted into ubuntu and did a software update. 21 packages were updated but after reboot am permanently stuck at the UBUNTU welcome screen with few dots
flashing. Pls help as am still new to ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Pls run your system in "Recovery mode" and fix any broken issues and reboot and see whether it works or not.I think you have problem with the video driver and it might not installed properly as you said u had error message during upgrade.Do a back up with live media before going further so u r safe from losing data.

Comment: Please can u elaborate how to fix broken issues.I also think its a problem with nvidia graphic cards .After having read various forum posts i tried sudo lightdm and l0 and behold i got through to the login screen and could boot into the dektop but when i try the normal method of reboot or power off and boot it still hangs at the splash screen.